# Mockito not working when using Model Mapper

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an `User` class:

```
public class User {
   private Long id;
   private String ssn;
   private float height;
   private float weight;
}
```

And an `UpdateUserDTO` class:

```
public class UpdateUserDTO {
   private float height;
   private float weight;
}
```

And an `UserDTO` class:

```
public class UserDTO {
   private Long id;
   private float height;
   private float weight;
}
```

I've used `Model Mapper` to map the updated fields from `updateUserDTO` to `user`, which comes from the DB.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final ModelMapper mapper;

    public UserDTO update(long userId, UpdateUserDTO updateUserDTO) {
        User user = getUserById(userId);
        mapper.map(updateUserDTO, user);
        user = repository.save(user);
        return mapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    @Test
    void updateWithSuccess() {
        long userId = 1L;

        UpdateUserDTO requestUpdateUserDTO = UpdateUserDTO.builder().height(1f).weight(1f).build();
        User userFromDB = User.builder().id(1L).ssn("123").height(50f).weight(50f).build();
        User userAfterMap = User.builder().id(1L).ssn("123").height(50f).weight(50f).build();
        UserDTO response = UserDTO.builder().id(1L).height(50f).weight(50f).build();

        Mockito.when(repository.findById(userId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userFromDB));
        Mockito.when(mapper.map(requestUpdateUserDTO, userFromDB)).thenReturn(userAfterMap);
        Mockito.when(repository.save(userFromDB)).thenReturn(userFromDB);
        Mockito.when(mapper.map(userFromDB, UserDTO.class)).thenReturn(response);
    }

    service.update(userId, requestUpdateUserDTO);

    ArgumentCaptor<User> userCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);

    assertEquals(requestUpdateUserDTO.getHeight(), userCaptor.getValue().getHeight());
    assertEquals(requestUpdateUserDTO.getWeight(), userCaptor.getValue().getWeight());
}
```

But the first `Mockito.when()` line does not even compile, because `mapper.map()` is a `void` method, so it does not expect any return values.

I've also tried:

```
Mockito.when(mapper.map(any(), any())).thenReturn(updatedUser);
```

Which does compile, but the `mapper.map()` doesn't work at all. Any of the fields are updated.

I've also tried:

```
Mockito.doReturn(updatedUser).when(mapper).map(any(), any());
```

But it doesn't work either.

I receive the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :5.0
Actual   :3.0
```

That's because `mapper.map()` does not work.

Does anyone know how I can mock this Mapper properly?

Thanks!

Comment: There is too little information. You are mocking a mapper, but is that the one being used? There are parts missing from your test as the current one simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum, I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: Make sure that you have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` method in your classes, else they won't match and either nothing will execute or `null` will be returned. Also the `map` as you stated is `void` so how can it return anything in the first place. Finally by mocking that you aren't really testing anything (apart from the mocking framework).

Comment: Like @M.Deinum said: The parameters inside the `when()` part of defining your mock behavior does search for a equal match. Your objects are same by content but differ by reference. Implement `equals()` and `hash()` to compare by content or use the `any()` approach.
If you really want to verify you can even use some thing called `captor` that can be a placeholder and save the actual used value -> but equals/hash method definition will do the same.

Comment: Even if I use `Mockito.when(mapper.map(any(), any())).thenReturn(updatedUser);`, the mapper is not executed at all, and the class `User` does not change, even adding `Equals` and `HashCode` methods. The code is not returning the `updatedUser` as it should.

Comment: For void methods you can choose doNothing() or doAnswer(), but they may provide little value https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to assert on? That the mocked mapper or repository are configured correctly?

The only thing you *could* assert here is that your builders work correctly, but I think that's the wrong test for that.

You don't have to assert on the results of the mocked stuff, you don't want to test Mockito itself, right?

If the mocks were not called correctly, you would get `null` there everywhere and therefore "earn" a `NullPointerException`. (So also the `ArgumentCaptor` is not necessary imo.)

What you should assert for is the result of the call to `service.update`, that it returns something equal to `response`. Make sure to implement `equals` and `hashcode` in your DTOs properly therefore!

And for the first call to `mapper.map` you don't need a rule what to return, but you should `verify` that it was called correctly.

UPDATE: example for my suggested method:

```java
@Test
void updateWithSuccess() {
    final long userId = 1L;

    // not using the builders here just because I didn't want to implement them but used records instead.
    UpdateUserDTO requestUpdateUserDTO = new UpdateUserDTO(18f,36f);
    User userFromDB = new User(33L, "ssn", 17f, 35f);
    UserDTO response = new UserDTO(33L, 18f, 36f);

    Mockito.doReturn(Optional.of(userFromDB)).when(repository).findById(userId);
    Mockito.doReturn(userFromDB).when(repository).save(userFromDB);
    Mockito.doReturn(response).when(mapper).map(userFromDB, UserDTO.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mapper).map(requestUpdateUserDTO, userFromDB);

    UserDTO result = service.update(userId, requestUpdateUserDTO);

    Assertions.assertEquals(response, result);
    Mockito.verify(mapper).map(requestUpdateUserDTO, userFromDB);
}
```

I suppose that the result from `repository.findById` is returned by `service.getUserById`.
You also could use mocks for your User and UserDTO instances, but I used records for easier of rebuilding your test and as they are `final` the effort to mock them would be higher.

The problem you have in your test is that you use `doReturn` for the mocking of `mapper.map(requestUpdateUserDTO, userFromDB)`, but this method does not return the new value, instead it modifies the second parameter. This is not supported by mocks - and not necessary for a test. You can just verify that the method was called (remember: you neither want to test the correct behaviour nor configuration of the ModelMapper with this test!)

Comment: I want to assert that the method `repository.save()` received the right arguments. That's why I am using `ArgumentCaptor`. Actually that

Comment: Actually even if I assert the object returned in the `service.update` method (`UserDTO`, which is supposed to have the updated values) the test won't work, because the mappers are not working properly.

Comment: You just have to make sure to test this properly in your rule to the mock of `repository.save()` then. If the wrong parameter is given, the mock will return `null` and therefore your next call to `mapper.map` with `null` will also return `null` and _this_ will not be equal to the expected result of `service.update` that you should create an assertion for.

Comment: If this is a real unit test you just have to make sure that all interactions to other methods are done properly. As your code doesn't do any calculations or assignments, you can take anything of a suitable class - you even could mock your model and DTO instances.

Comment: You have to make sure though that `getUserById` returns the right value!

Comment: Sorry, @cyberbrain if I did not get it right, but the mapper mocks are not working. Could you please suggest any code changes? So that I can test and accept your answer. These lines `Mockito.when(mapper.map(requestUpdateUserDTO, userFromDB)).thenReturn(userAfterMap);` are not executed during execution, so the object `userFromDB` is not updated.

Comment: I updated my answer to add an example and further explanations. Hope that it helps :)